# Could Anyone tell me the magento vanilla version number?

Tags: magento-enterprise, importexport

I am new for magento frame work could anyone tell me magento vanilla version number

Comment: Can you clarify what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this discussion will help you.

https://vanillaforums.org/discussion/27373/magento-and-vanilla-forums